# Moving the header when in a UITableView's edit mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I've got a UITableView with custom cells and also a custom header, like so:

```
--------------------
|   Header         |
--------------------
|     cell         |
|     cell         |
|     etc          |
```

Whenever I put it into edit mode, in order to delete cells, it looks like this

```
--------------------
|   Header         |
--------------------
-  |     cell        
-  |     cell        
-  |     etc
```

As you can see, the table cells are moved right-wards to make room for for the minus icons. However, the header stays in the same position. How would I move the header to the right, to match the cells x-postion below?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Created a different nib for the edit mode header, and then show it only when editing:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// CustomHeader creates the header view
CustomHeader *tableHeader;  
if (self.tableView.editing) 
{
    tableHeader = (CustomHeader *)[CustomHeader headerFromNibNamed:@"CustomHeaderEditMode"];        
} else {
    tableHeader = (CustomHeader *)[CustomHeader headerFromNibNamed:@"CustomHeader"];
}
return tableHeader;
}
```

Comment: Using nibs like this is not very performant -- loading them is notoriously slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a label in your header in -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section like this :

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, self.tableView.bounds.size.width - 45,50)];

    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    if(self.tableView.editing && section==0)
    {
       label.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.tableView.bounds.size.width,150);
        NSString *NewSection = @"My new header message in edit mode d\n\n OK";
        label.text = NewSection;
    }
    else   {
      label.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.tableView.bounds.size.width,40);  
    label.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
       }
```

[sectionHeader addSubview:label];
Then add it to your header view

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
UIView* viewObj = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 40];
```

`UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];`

```
headerLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
if(self.tableView.editing && section==0)
{
   headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(cellpositionX,0,self.tableView.bounds.size.width - cellpositionX,40);
    NSString *NewSection = @"My new header message in edit mode d\n\n OK";
    headerLabel.text = NewSection;
}
else   {
  headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.tableView.bounds.size.width,40);  
headerLabel.text = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
   }
[viewObj addSubview:headerLabel];
return viewObj;}
```

In the above code you can pass the x value in cellpositionX.

Also each time when TableView starts and ends editing. you need to reload TableView

I hope this will solve your problem